# simplexml_load_string how to prevent namespare error

Tags: php, simplexml

How can I ignore namespace errors using simplexml_load_string function?
I have only to extract first-level nodes from an xml, I don't care about namespace definition.

@simplexml_load_string is not a solution because I need a Xml object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, null, LIBXML_NOERROR);
```